# Eclipse. Variable to get the class name

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proper usage of Java -D command-line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045608/proper-usage-of-java-d-command-line-parameters)

I am trying to launch this command from Eclipse:

```
mvn test -Dtest=com.yyy.xxx.myTest
```

So to configure the command in the "Run Configurations" I need an Eclipse variable to get com.yyy.xxx.myTest

My idea is to launch the command after to select the class.

Here, I have not found the variable:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm

Any idea about the variable?

Comment: As I understand answer on your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045608/proper-usage-of-java-d-command-line-parameters "Proper usage of Java -D command-line parametersr")

Comment: It seems that my previous answer is not quite correct. Looks like you need **${java_type_name}** variable

Comment: Using ${java_type_name} the behaviour is not correct. The command launches all tests. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the behaviour is not correct but your Answer YES. I have inspected the launched command and I have got:  -Dtest=com.yyy.xxx.myTest

Comment: Please CAMOBAP, replace your original answer with the correct one, to avoid the duplicate question. Thanks