# Jar and java.library.path

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to use DLL's from a specific place from the disk (because I am using JNotify library).

Using Netbeans 7.4, the following happened:

My temporary program only does:

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`

As VM options in Netbeans I have set: `-Djava.library.path=D:/JNotify-dll/`. Program outputs: `D:/Jnotify-dll/`.

When I run it as normal `java <jarfile>`: It gives main class not set, while I did set it in Netbeans options.

When I run it as `java -jar <jarfile>`: It gives me my `%PATH%` variable.

When I run it as `java -jar <jarfile> -Djava.library.path=D:/JNotify-dll/` it **still** gives me my `%PATH%` variable.

Does anyone have any clue what is going on? I am getting real tired of it.

The `MANIFEST.MF` generated by Netbeans:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.1
Created-By: 1.7.0_25-b17 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/ORM.jar lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar lib/co
 mmons-dbcp-1.4-javadoc.jar lib/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar lib/commons-pool-
 1.6-javadoc.jar lib/commons-pool-1.6.jar lib/jnotify-0.94.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: bf4.bf4logreader.BF4LogReader
```

**EDIT:** `java -jar -Djava.library.path=D:/JNotify-dll/ <jarfile>`, but I'd still appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to change the order of your command line arguments:

```
java -Djava.library.path=D:/JNotify-dll/ -jar <jarfile>
```

See also:

- [Proper usage of Java -D command-line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045608/proper-usage-of-java-d-command-line-parameters)