# Springboot read runtime java arguments in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I am running a SpringBoot application and wanted tomcat access logs to be stored in a directory whose path has to be passed in runtime JVM arguments, because it has to be run on 2 different application containers and the paths can be given by java runtime argument only.

application.properties

```
server.tomcat.basedir=${log.location}
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)
```

Giving this tomcat base directory location for work and logs as :

```
java -jar SpringBoot.jar -Dlog.location=/apps/pricing/logs
```

But unfortunately it is not affecting. Tomcat work and log directories are being created from the place I am running java command inside a new directory with name "${log.location}", but not creating inside actual log.location=/apps/pricing/logs which is existing directory.

If anyone has any idea please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-D` options belong before the `-jar` option:

More info: [Proper usage of Java -D command-line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045608/proper-usage-of-java-d-command-line-parameters)