# How do I read runtime variables inside java class?

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a java app that looks something like this

```
java -Dconfig.dir = ../../.. -jar blah..
```

how can I access this config.dir in java application at run time.I am trying to load a properties file that will be there at run time.So I want to load this in file stream

Comment: `System.getProperty("config.dir")`

Comment: @Glains in this case this will not work as value for `config.dir` property is not passed as a parameter to the main method

Comment: ty Ivan I will try that.

Comment: @Praveen do not use spaces in java command line `-Dconfig.dir = ../../..` use it as `-Dconfig.dir=../../..` and then use @Ivan comment   BTW: @Glains you are not right.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045608/proper-usage-of-java-d-command-line-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivan gave the correct answer in a comment.

System.getProperty("config.dir")

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, you need to add the location of the properties file in the class path and then follow the steps given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/333385/1235935) answer.

If you really want to read the -D parameter, refer to @Ivan comment

Comment: yeah cant have properties file inside project.Will foolow Ivan's comment

Comment: @Praveen You don't need to have the properties file in project to be able to add the location in classpath. You can add any random director location to the classpath using the `-classpath` java command line switch

Comment: ooh I was not aware of that  let me try that