# How to override logback default variable using command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have following variable in `logback-sring.xml` and I want to override its default value using value supplied in command line.

```
<property name="log_root" value="${log.root:-logapp/logs}"/>
 <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${log_root}/app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log_root}/archived/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days worth of history, but at most 1GB -->
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%level %d [%thread] %logger{15} - %msg %ex{2}%nopex%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

I tried to override the value during the jar call:

```
java -jar app.jar -Dlog.root=logappv2/logs
```

But the app always use the default log.root value.
What is possibly the cause?

Comment: Please include the part of `logback-spring.xml` referring `log_root`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `-Dlog.root=logappv2/logs` before `-jar`, like.

`java -Dlog.root=logappv2/logs -jar app.jar`

Reference:
[Proper usage of Java -D command-line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045608/proper-usage-of-java-d-command-line-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

This is the variable you are passing via command line ${log.root} but I do not see its usage.

Comment: i have added the usage